# On Dirichlet series and Firoozbakht's conjecture

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series

On assumption of the [Firoozbakht's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firoozbakht%27s_conjecture) (this is the **Wikipedia**, but the reference is for [Carlos Rivera's Page](http://www.primepuzzles.net/conjectures/conj_030.htm)) one has that can writes informally the **Dirichlet series** in LHS of this inequality $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{p_n^{1/n}-p_{n+1}^{1/(1+n)}}{n^s}<2+\left(\frac{1}{2^s}-1\right)3^{\frac{1}{2}}+\left(\frac{1}{3^s}-\frac{1}{2^s}\right)5^{\frac{1}{3}}+\left(\frac{1}{4^s}-\frac{1}{3^s}\right)7^{\frac{1}{4}}+\ldots$$
that is a direct consequence of the conjecture.

It was the only calculation that this morning did to explore the conjecture using Dirichlet series. My purpose is learn easy facts on Dirichlet series, and edit funny questions in this site. I am specially interesting in the calculation of abscissas of absolute convergence because those are the keys to start the calculations for bounds of partial sums of Dirichlet series $|\sum^N|$. Then

> **Question.** It is possible to determine approximately the abscissa of absolute convergence of previous Dirichlet series? **Thanks in advance.**

My calculations were that there exists the corresponding **abscissas of convergence absolute** for the Dirichlet series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{p_n^{1/n}}{n^s}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{p_{n+1}^{1/(n+1)}}{n^s}$, say us $\sigma_a$ and $\sigma_{a'}$ respectively. I've deduced this since (and there is a similar calculation for the other Dirichlet series, the first of them) the **Prime Number Therorem implies** $$p_{n+1}^{\frac{1}{n+1}}\sim ((n+1)\log(n+1))^{\frac{1}{n+1}}$$
thus $\sim 1$ since $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}\log((n+1)\log(n+1))=0,$$ and from this I've said that there exists a real $\sigma_{a'}$ being the abscissa of absolute convergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{p_{n+1}^{1/(n+1)}}{n^s}.$$

Thus I believe that it is neccesary an approximation for $\sigma_{a}$ and $\sigma_{a'}$ with the purpose to claim that $\max\{\sigma_{a}, \sigma_{a'}\}$ is the required abscissa of absolute convergence that answers the **Question.**

I don't know if this exercise was in the literature. But there are a lot of literature in **arXiv**. If there are some useful fact from those, it is you recognize that some recipe that could be useful, add the reference and I will try read the proposition in arXiv.

Comment: replace $p_n$ by $n \ln n = e^{\ln n + \ln\ln n}$ so that $p_n^{1/n} \approx  e^{\frac{\ln n}{n}} \to 1$, and the radius of convergence of $\sum_n p_n n^{-s}$ is $1$. for $p_{n+1}^{1/n} - p_n^{1/n}$ it is not harder, write it as $e^{\frac{\ln p_{n+1}}{n}}-e^{\frac{\ln p_{n}}{n}} \approx \frac{\ln p_{n+1}-\ln p_n}{n} = \mathcal{O}(n^\epsilon)$ so the radius of convergence is $0$.

Comment: Very thanks much, now I study your calculations. THen if one has a series with radius of convergence 0, one can not define such series. I hope that you was well. Very thanks much @user1952009

Comment: come on, I meant abscissa of convergence.. it is a Dirichlet series https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Dirichlet_series#Abscissa_of_convergence

Comment: I am sorry for last comment, now I understand $\Re s=0$ is the line of convergence. Very thanks much, and my apologizes for my mistake, I was not focused @user1952009 Then very thanks much for your statement.

Comment: I wasn't focused, I meant $\frac{\ln p_{n+1}-\ln p_n}{n} = \mathcal{O}(n^{-1+\epsilon})$ SO the abscissa of convergence is $0$

Comment: Thanks one more time, you are welcome @user1952009